# Is there an easy way to export images in their original state in Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, post-processing

There are a couple of photos that I have adjusted using camera raw in Lightroom. Now I want to export those images in their original state (before adjustments). But I can't find any shortcut to do it.

What I'm having to do now is:

- first copy all settings
- reset all changes
- export original image with specific resolution
- then paste settings.

Is there any way to do this directly because I have so many photos that I want to export in both the original and adjusted states for before/after image comparisons.

Comment: Why not just copy the files using your local filesystem? Those are the originals, which are never altered by LR.

Answer (score 11):

It's easy.. Just go to your Export settings >File Settings >Format --> Original.

Here:

[image]

Your photo's original state will be exported.. Just choose "Original" and export all your photos ;)

Comment: That option exports in the original files file format, not the original file without any prior changes.

Comment: No it exports the original file without any prior changes! I tried it just now.. It does

Comment: Hmmm, so it appears (which, in my opinion is a ridiculous implementation). anyway +1 for both comment and answer.

Comment: seems almost like a bug to me. definitely not what i would have expected, for jpegs at least. the manual just says:"If you choose Original, Lightroom exports the image data in the same format that the original was captured in, and no File Settings options are available. When exporting original raw files, metadata changes are exported in an accompanying sidecar file."

Comment: Whatever it is, it's serving our purpose here.

Comment: When I set to file format Original it export original image at its full resolution but I want to export at some specific resolution (want to export original photo at some specific resolution). It does not do that.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to do this is:

1. make virtual copy of images
2. reset settings on this virtual copy
3. export jpeg from virtual copy
4. destroy it (if you will not need it anymore)

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now, but is somewhat lengthy. And I don't find any easy way to do this.

Comment: @SumitPMakwana, based on your question I do not see easy and sample way to accomplish it (at least with LR)

Comment: How is it lengthy? Seems like 5 minutes:

 - Select all
 - Create virtual copies
 - Show only virtuals
 - Select all
 - Go to develop
 - Turn on Auto-sync
 - Zero the things you want zeroed
 - Verify that it worked
 - Export

Answer (score 0):

First, right click on the retouched photo, choose copy before's settings to after, then export it as jpg. At last, undo copying by Ctrl+Z, hope it can help.