# Is there an easy way to export photos from Lightroom in original format if they're unedited?

Tags: jpeg, lightroom-5, image-compression

When I export a folder or collection from Lightroom, I want unedited photos exported in their original format (like DNG, ARW, PNG) and edited photos exported in a chosen format, like JPEG.

Is there an easy way to do this, short of using a Smart Collection to identify edited photos and exporting them separately?

This is not a dupe of [Is there an easy way to export images in their original state in Lightroom?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61074) , as some people have voted, because that question wants to export originals ignoring edits made in Lightroom, while this question wants the edits exported.

This is not a dupe of [Does JPEG-to-JPEG export Lightroom reapply compression?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34190/does-jpeg-to-jpeg-export-lightroom-reapply-compression), either, because the original format may not be JPG — it could be DNG, ARW, PNG, TIFF, etc. This question wants unedited photos exported in the original format, not in JPEG.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there an easy way to export images in their original state in Lightroom?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61074/is-there-an-easy-way-to-export-images-in-their-original-state-in-lightroom)

Comment: Not at all. Read the last paragraph of the updated question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does JPEG-to-JPEG export Lightroom reapply compression?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/34190/does-jpeg-to-jpeg-export-lightroom-reapply-compression)

Comment: Not a dupe — see the last paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: NO. Long Answer: Lightroom only allows the specification of one output format, so regardless of what you have selected, all exported images will be that format. You can select "Original" in the export to export the raw files, but in order to do what you want you would need to do two exports, one for the unedited photos and one for the edited photos.

One way would be to select the photos you want to export and mark them with a flag, label, keyword, or something you can filter on. Then click Attribute, filter based on that "something" and toggle the Edited/Unedited filter and then Export.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the question is somewhat meaningless. ARW is the extension for Sony raw format files (DNG is Adobe's attempt to standardize raw files). These files are not, until they are demosaiced, actual images in the first place.

When you import the ARW (or NEF or any other raw file format) into Lightroom, the image you view is not the unaltered raw file but instead is the processed version generated by demosaicing software. The same is true when you chimp on the back of the camera - you are not looking at the raw file because that is not an image yet. The computer in the camera performs the demosic function.

So, simply copying the raw files from one place to another is the only way to "export the original file", but again, raw files are not images yet.

Comment: "Raw files are not images yet" is missing the point -- I can double click them and they display, like JPEGs. As far as I'm concerned for the purpose of this question, RAWs are images. Besides, by your definition, JPEGs aren't images, either, since they require processing to display, like decompression, (inverse) DCT, etc.